# Python Gtk3 | Gtk.TextView() dies with pango_layout_new error

Tags: python, gtk3

My Python (2.7) + Gtk# + Windows 7 program is dying when calling the constructor for a Gtk.TextView:

```
t = Gtk.TextView()
```

And this error is printed to stderr:

```
  (python.exe:151468): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
```

This is only happening in a big complex program, and does not happen in a simple test script. I don't know what could be triggering it.

(Errors printed out from within Gtk are really frustrating when using the Python bindings (gi.repository) because we cannot see what is going on or catch the exception...)